# Custom database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to develop a simple application in Android, but i haven't idea to how realize a part of this project.

The problem is the developing of the database, in particular i don't know how represent the informations that i must save in the db.

What i must save is a structure that represent a list of working shifts.

Each day is divided in four parts :

- Night (24.00 - 08:00)
- Morning (08.00 - 14.00)
- Afternoon (14.00 - 20.00)
- Evening (20.00 - 24.00)

In each turn (Night or Morning or arthernoon or evening) one or max three worker can may decide to partecipate.

For example:

Day : 13/04/15 
Night : Person a , Person b, Person c 
Morning : Person d, Person e, Person f

A list of worker must be present in a table linked at the rest of the database

Comment: Relational db. One table to hold the hours, the other to hold what users take each shift, linked by the hours_id.

Comment: @Sobrique No more, because i don't know how i can link all the relations, actually i have only created and popolated one table named "Worker" that contain all the personal data worker (Firts name, last name, age ecc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a classic [n-to-m relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) between a turns and works, meaning one worker can be assigned to many turns but also one turn has many workers.

So the actual table design might look something like that:

[image]

Please note, that i chose an `int` for `turn_time` meaning you'd have to map between your `turn_time` in your db and your source code. Probably the best option would be constants like so:

```
<?php
const TURN_TURN_TIME_NIGHT     = 0;
const TURN_TURN_TIME_MORNING   = 1;
const TURN_TURN_TIME_AFTERNOON = 2;
const TURN_TURN_TIME_EVENING   = 3;
//...
?>
```

This will reduce some bloat in your tables.

Please also note that you'd have to limit the number of assigned workers to a certain turn in your business logic. That way you're also free to change the numbers of workers per turn at any given time without having to mess with your DB schema.